# Replacing if-­‐statements with a case statement

Tags: vhdl

I would like to know how to replace an `if` statement with a `case` statement.

The `if` statement is

```
architecture super_mux_v1 of mux_case is
begin
    process (X,SEL) is
    begin
        if (SEL = "000") then
            Y <= X(0);
        elsif (SEL = "001") then
            Y <= X(1);
        elsif (SEL = "010") then
            Y <= X(2);
        elsif (SEL = "011") then
            Y <= X(3);
        elsif (SEL = "100") then
            Y <= X(4);
        elsif (SEL = "101") then
            Y <= X(5);
        elsif (SEL = "110") then
            Y <= X(6);
        else
            Y <= X(7);
        end if;
    end process;
end super_mux_v1;
```

My solution can be found below but I am getting some errors (case statement)

```
architecture super_mux_v1 of mux_case is
begin
    process (X,SEL) is
    begin
        case SEL is
        when "000" => Y <= X(0);
        when "001" => Y <= X(1);
        when "010" => Y <= X(2);
        when "011" => Y <= X(3);
        when "100" => Y <= X(4);
        when "101" => Y <= X(5);
        when "110" => Y <= X(6);
        end case;
    end process;
end super_mux_v1;
```

When I start compilation it comes up with an error saying

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it belongs on SO

Comment: You forgot the `when others =>` clause. Whether that is your problem is anybody's guess since you also forgot to tell us what the errors are. And you forgot to turn off CAPS LOCK too...

Comment: @ScottSeidman The question is bad, but on SO, really? VHDL?

Comment: user3880651, what is the line 37 with the error? Also check my answer - you should remove `is` from the process declaration

Comment: @pipe Ya on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (tagged [vhdl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl). Of course the question [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) would want a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - the declarations, X, Y, SEL presumably in an entity declaration).

Comment: I could not reproduce the error given in the screenshot which Quartus-II version 13.1. Which Quartus-II version are you using? Can you please give a complete example. And where is line 37?

Answer (score 3):

Like the VHDL reference guide says (for instance [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/cases.html))

> All possible choices must be included, unless the others clause is
>   used as the last choice

In your `if` version you used it, since you wrote `else ...`. In your `switch` one, however, you didn't.

Try writing

```
    case SEL is
    when "000" => Y <= X(0);
    when "001" => Y <= X(1);
    when "010" => Y <= X(2);
    when "011" => Y <= X(3);
    when "100" => Y <= X(4);
    when "101" => Y <= X(5);
    when "110" => Y <= X(6);
    when others => Y <= X(7);
    end case;
```

This should fix your problems

EDIT: There is another problem in your code: `process (X,SEL) is` should be `process (X,SEL)` (without `is`)

Comment: Without seeing a declaration for X how do you know it has an element with an index value of 7?  Now withdrawn, support for `is` was required in IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (IEEE Standard for VHDL Register Transfer Level (RTL) Synthesis, now withdrawn) 8.9.2 Process statement (but not -1999 same clause, noting `is` support was required in 8.4.5 Component declarations). It speaks to the age of the QuartusII synthesis tool.

Comment: @user1155120 well, the OP said that the first example worked, so since he put X(7) in all the other cases I just copied it. As for the is, I couldn't understand if you are saying that it is needed or not ;) in every example I saw the is was missing..

Comment: `is` is optional in a process statement (and a component declaration). The question is whether or not the tool will accept it or not?

Comment: @user1155120 thank you for your comment.. Yes, if the OP said what is the line giving that error it would be easier to fix...

Comment: The particular VHDL analyzer won't specify any closer than the beginning of a statement for this syntax error. There's a historical presumption you provide valid VHDL code based on design flow.